# What is the Sufi interpretation and method to control anger?

Tags: sufism, anger

I just answered [How to control anger according to sunnah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/21751/17163), and it struck me as likely that Sufis might have a different interpretation of anger and a different approach to coping with anger, perhaps more spiritual than other Muslims.

Googling `sufi anger` gives two references:

- [Sufi University](http://sufiuniversity.org/2011/02/spiritual-tip-to-heal-anger/): He says that if you’re angry, then you do the Sufi practice of tawbah and return to divine love now. The tawbah practice can be used to bypass by the past and the 'root' of the problem.
- [Sufispirit.com.au](http://sufispirit.com.au/feature/sufi-meditation-control-of-anger/): When a person gets angry, this is a form of pride. They are saying, 'I am better than you'.

So it seems likely that there's a different attitude in Sufism to anger.  However, I don't know how reliable/accurate these references are among Sufis.

**Question**: What is the Sufi interpretation and method to control anger?

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, would you want to spiritual definition of anger and ways to control it using spiritual practices? Not necessarily of sufi type origin.

Answer (score 0):

According to the great Sufi scholar of Islam Hzt. Nizamuddin Sila of New Delhi India the FORGIVENESS is the only solution of anger. He has said that if you do not forgive than it will  change into jealous.

Answer (score 0):

One of the practises of sufis is to meditate on the ninety nine names of Allah. Whilst this includes *al-Rahim*, the Compassionate it also includes *al-Muntaqim*, the Avengeful

Noticeably, this has an aspect of anger; thus, it is correct to be angry snd avenge when one is *justified* I'm doing so. This is quite unlike Nietszchean  notions of contempt, where it is regarded as a supreme end.

Here, it is a means; and the end should be harmony.