# Is there a basis in the texts for shoe throwing?

Tags: tradition

There are lots of examples of [people](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RFH7C3vkK4) getting [shoes thrown at](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82MpOotYG08) them for various disagreements. I recently read [this article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/iraq/3776970/Arab-culture-the-insult-of-the-shoe.html) that presents it as a tradition.

Does someone know of a religious basis for this? (other than shoes being forbidden in mosques)

I am not asking for any moral judgement about shoe-throwing, or about the people receiving shoes in the examples in the links.

Thanks in advance.

Sidenote : This question is not meant to be a critic. Personally, I find throwing shoes during disagreements a quite acceptable "habit". Not only does a shoe do limited harm, but it also gives the time to the thrower to calm down and think about his action while he fetches his shoes back or goes home bare-foot.

Comment: Please mention why if you downvote. Please also mention if the linked article is erronated.

Comment: Of course there is no basis for it. Throwing shoes might just be an attempt to show or express anger. And throwing shoes or any other cultural behavior like pointing finger and such are not accepted. See this which is related to anger: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21751/how-to-control-anger-according-to-sunnah

Comment: I downvoted because this has nothing to do with Islam.

Comment: @G.Bach The whole point of the question is to know whether it has anything to do with islam or not. There could be for instance a hadith about a religious figure throwing a shoe at someone else, or a jinn. I would not know it.

Comment: If this is on-topic, then every question of "does type X of human behavior have a basis in Islam" is on-topic. I doubt that's intended.

Comment: Since when were shoes forbidden at Mosques?

Comment: @G.Bach Does it include questions of the kind "does tradition X common in muslim country Y have a religious basis?". I looked for something similar in the tour, I did not find anything.

Comment: [Cultural practices of Muslim communities are explicitly offtopic.](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: probably you should ask in other site like history se, and the article does not mention "islam", i searched with ctrl+f.

Answer (score 2):

There is no basis for it.

Throwing shoes might just be an attempt to show or express anger. And throwing shoes or any other cultural behavior like pointing finger and such are not accepted. See [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21751/how-to-control-anger-according-to-sunnah) which is related to anger

And as it is said in the [article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/iraq/3776970/Arab-culture-the-insult-of-the-shoe.htmleasilly) you read:

> Showing the sole of your shoe has long been an insult in **Arab culture**

Understanding that it is an Arab culture (not all Arabs), would deem it to be a cultural "practice" and as G.Bach stated in the comments, that it has nothing to do with Islam. When this is understood, you will easily be able to filter out other cultural questions that has nothing to do with Islam, especially when they go against the Islamic tradition (in this case, how to behave when you get angry).

Comment: I found this : A drunkard was brought to the Prophet (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam). He said, "Give him a beating." Then some beat him with their hands, some with their shoes, and some with (a folded) piece of cloth. When he left, someone said to him: "May Allah disgrace you!" The Prophet (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) said, "Do not help Satan overcome him by uttering such words." Here (Book 18, Hadith 1562 ) : http://altahleel.com/hadith-explorer/riyadussaliheen/356/page/3 . I don't know how much people read it, though.

Comment: @user5751924 Whatever the tafsir of that hadith is, it is not a basis of throwing with shoes (or beat with shoes), in this situation (whatever the true tafsir of the hadith is), its generally speaking about beating. It happened that someone used his shoe, but that is not a basis to throw or hit people with shoes. Or it may mean that they beat with what ever they find to beat with, as you see some hit with their hands, some with a piece of cloth and some with their shoes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's not throwing, but beating:

[image]

It seems to come up sporadically, but it does not look like part of Islam.

1. You mention the hadith:

   > When An-Nuaman or his son was brought in a state of drunkenness, Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) ordered all those who were present in the house to beat him. I was one of those who beat him. **We beat him with shoes and palm-leaf stalks.** -- Sahih al-Bukhari 2316 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/40/15)); see also Sahih al-Bukhari 6777 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/86/6))
2. Beatings with shoes we mentioned in tafsir in relation to [Qur'an 4:16](https://quran.com/4:16):

   > And the two who commit [unlawful sexual intercourse] among you, dishonor them both. But if they repent and correct themselves, leave them alone. Indeed, Allah is ever Accepting of repentance and Merciful.

   [Tafsir al-Jalalayn](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=1&tTafsirNo=74&tSoraNo=4&tAyahNo=16&tDisplay=yes&LanguageId=2) states:

   > And when two of you read wa’lladhāni or wa’lladhānni men commit it that is a lewd act adultery or homosexual intercourse **punish them both with insults and beatings with sandals**; but if they repent of this lewd act and make amends through good action then leave them be and do not harm them. God ever turns relenting to those who repent and is Merciful to them. This verse is abrogated ...

   [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/839) likewise quotes a tafsir by Ibn Katheer "Ibn ‘Abbas, may Allah be pleased with him, Sa‘eed ibn Jubayr and others said: i.e., by putting them to public shame and hitting them with shoes."
3. IslamWeb writes about [The harm and torture to which Abu Bakr was subjected](http://www.islamweb.net/prophet/index.php?page=showarticle&id=152921):

   > The Companions, may Allah be pleased with them, endured extreme hardship and sacrificed their souls and property for the sake of Allah The Almighty. The noble Muslims were not spared from this suffering and trials. Abu Bakr, may Allah be pleased with him, was harmed and soil was flung at his head. **He was beaten in Al-Masjid Al-Haraam with shoes** until his face became swollen and unrecognizable and then carried to his house in his garment in a state between life and death.

Comment: Note that memri has been known to mistranslate opportunistically; the actions shown in the screencapped interview pretty much speak for themselves of course.